# Create new string from 1st character of each word of a multi word string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a need for a Windows NT command script to do the following:
 - Read variable string from command line
 - Take that variable and create new string based off 1st byte of each word

The incoming string in the Windows NT command script is `%1`.
The string may vary in length and number of words, but always ends with `(something here) [something there]`.

Example - Incoming value from command line including quotes:

```
"This is my string for a new name (comment) [comment 2]"
```

The string I need to create is:

```
Timsfann
```

These characters are from the 1st letter in each of the words in the above string and stopping when it gets to the parenthesis in `(comment)`.

The above string will be concatenated with a date/time string to create a unique filename.  The finished string should be set to a system variable so that programs can find the finished value.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've been attempting using a `FOR` loop, but can't seem to get it to work as desired.

Comment: Please show us your existing code.

Comment: Although you included many explanations, some of them are confusing. The command used to _"**Read variable string** from command line"_ is `set /P`. You add: _"Take that **variable**..."_ and then: _"The incoming string in the Windows NT command script is `%1`"_. You should note that `%1` is _not_ a "variable" that could be "read" from command line (when the program run), but a _parameter_ that is placed after the batch file name (before the program run). Although this may seem a pedantic explanation, the use of the right terms may be important in the description of more complex problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one of a few ways you could do this.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims=(" %%G IN ("%~1") do set "line=%%G"

FOR %%G IN (%line%) DO (
    set tline=%%G
    set code=!code!!tline:~0,1!
)
echo %code%
pause
```

Comment: Squashman - thank you for your answer.  It works perfectly in the script I'm writing.  By examining your code I am sure to learn more about how this works in the FOR statements.  I think my main problem was the variables and using ! around them.  Thanks again for such a nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

[@Crimsyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8822110/crimsyn), if it's easier for you to understand, here's another one of the few ways, *which doesn't use delayed expansion or the FOR statement*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Call :Loop %~1
Echo(%oStr%&Pause
Exit/B

:Loop
If "%~1"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set "iStr=%~1"
If "%iStr:~,1%"=="(" GoTo :EOF
Set "oStr=%oStr%%iStr:~,1%"
Shift&GoTo Loop
```

Comment: This method don't works. It seems you disregard this description: The incoming string in the Windows NT command script is `%1`. Example - Incoming value from command line **including quotes**: `"This is my string for a new name (comment) [comment 2]"`

Answer (score 2):

Another one! Although simpler and shorter, this method could be harder to understand... **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=%~1 "
set "str=%str:(= " & rem %
set "result="
set "word=%str: =" & set "result=!result!!word:~0,1!" & set "word=%" 

echo %result%
```

Hint: execute it with `echo on`

Comment: if you `set "str=%~1 "` on `line 4` it would ensure that `%result%` will not be missing it's last character if the input string should be passed without it's expected `(` character or a trailing space. Shouldn't happen but, for the sake of a single space why not!

Comment: @Compo: You are right! **`:)`** The same point apply to the left paren...